# Linq to xml, retrieving generic interface-based list

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an XML document that looks like this

```
    <Elements>
     <Element>
      <DisplayName />
      <Type />
     </Element>
    </Elements>
```

I have an interface,

```
interface IElement
{
    string DisplayName {get;}
}
```

and a couple of derived classes:

```
public class AElement: IElement

public class BElement: IElement
```

What I want to do is write the most efficient query to iterate through the XML and create a list of `IElement`, containing `AElement` or `BElement`, based on the 'Type' property in the XML.

So far I have this:

```
IEnumerable<AElement> elements = 
    from xmlElement in XElement.Load(path).Elements("Element")
    where xmlElement.Element("type").Value == "AElement"
    select new AElement(xmlElement.Element("DisplayName").Value);

return elements.Cast<IElement>().ToList();
```

But this is only for `AElement`. Is there a way to add `BElement` in the same query, and also make it generic `IEnumerable<IElement>`? Or would I have to run this query once for each derived type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the conditional operator:

```
IEnumerable<IElement> elements = 
    from xmlElement in XElement.Load(path).Elements("Element")
    let type = (string)xmlElement.Element("Type")
    let name = (string)xmlElement.Element("DisplayName")
    select type == "AElement"
         ? (IElement)new AElement(name)
         : (IElement)new BElement(name);
```

Or, using regular syntax:

```
IEnumerable<IElement> elements =
    XElement.Load(path)
            .Elements("Element")
            .Select(xmlElement =>
{
    var type = (string)xmlElement.Element("Type");
    var name = (string)xmlElement.Element("DisplayName");

    switch (type)
    {
        case "AElement": return (IElement)new AElement(name);
        case "BElement": return (IElement)new BElement(name);
    }

    throw new Exception();
});
```

Comment: That would get nasty if he has more than 2 sub-types.

Comment: @Aren B: Indeed. I've added an alternative solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. How can I write switch statement in linq syntax? I gave an example of only AElement and BElement, but in reality there are more. Is the only way to do so is using regular syntax?

Comment: @Rita: `switch` is a statement,  not an expression, so you can't use it in LINQ syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<IElement> elements = 
    from e in XElement.Load(path).Elements("Element")
    let elType = e.Element("Type").Value
    let elName = e.Element("Name").Value
    where elType == "AElement" || elType == "BElement" 
    select 
        elType == "AElement" 
            ? (IElement) new AElement( name )
            : (IElement) new BElement( name );
```